# How do I passing string to another page with $stateParams?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular 1.5.x & babel. I want to passing a string in 1st page and then showing it in 2nd page.
I have these 2 states:

***1st state***

```
.state('outside'{
 url:'/outside',
 templateUrl: 'outside.html',
 controller: 'outsideCtrl'
})
```

***2nd state***

```
.state('inside',
 url:'/inside/:building',
 templateUrl: 'inside.html',
 controller: 'insideCtrl'
})
```

***my 2nd controller*** look like this.

```
constructor($stateParams) {
   this.Building : $stateParams.building;
}
```

***1st html***

```
<a ui-sref="inside ({building: 'castle'})"> castle </a>
<a ui-sref="inside ({building: 'blacksmith'})"> castle </a>
```

***2nd html***

```
<p>Okay, now you are in a {{insideCtrl.Building}} </p>
```

I still get it wrong because of the building is undefined, and also is it possible to passing a string ?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

add the param attribute in your state.

```
.state('inside',
 url:'/inside',
 templateUrl: 'inside.html',
 controller: 'insideCtrl',
 params: {
           building: ""
        }
})
```

in html, change ui-sref like below

```
ui-sref="inside({building : yourstringvaluevariable})"
```

in the second controller receive the parameter like this.

```
var newBuilding = $state.params.building;
```

Answer (score 1):

In inside controller you need get the param value via `$state`. You need to inject it to the controller.

```
$scope.building = $state.params.building;
```

And in HTML

```
<p>Okay, now you are in a {{building}} </p>
```